Straighten a line that is stretched due to camera movement
I need to do image processing to inverse a stretching that is caused by object movement while camera is taking picture.
The target resulting image is looking like this.
A. 
My current image is looking like this. I cannot really clearly make the item, but i Hope it can illustrate it. In this image,
the top part is stretched but the bottom part is not stretched
B. 
My thought process is to

detect the left facing and right facing lines.
mirror the right facing line so I can average the coordinates between those two (left and right).
image processing to resize the image so that the downward stretching part could be shorter (make the line straight again).

The 3rd part is done. The 2nd part, i can make do on it
I am having trouble for the first part.
how can I detect the left and right lines?
After do some thresholding, I can locate the black pixels, but I am not sure how to identify the left facing and right facing lines.

extra info for my thought process
For process 2, since it is a pattern, left and right lines should and are the same (they are a mesh pattern with same gradient). In every height in the image, they should be the same.

For process 3, in my image, the stretched part is stretched downward. This could be done by getting the gradient of the line from the unstretched part. Then use image processing to resize the shorten the stretched part, so that the gradient become the same.

This kind of task is not really possible... or very very difficult, like people currently doing their PhD about it difficult.

you are hiding the true problem from us. show us the true problem.

If mirroring the lines and averaging is legitimate/correct, you know more about the lines than you have told us.

@christophRackwitz I updated the queston.

you aren't taking pictures of fences though, or are you? what is the true "object" that moves? why does it move? -- guessing here, which I hate to do: this is optical inspection of some fabric or other flat sheet material that passes by a line scan camera at varying speeds

@ChristophRackwitz sorry, I didnt think that details are needed.Your guess are completely correct. The object is just a drawn line over some flat gray sheets.
and the stretching might be caused by both camera speed, and the object movement. I was thinking of reconstruct the image from camera speed and object movement, but since I have the mesh pattern, I am going with only image processing route.

@MarkSetchell I updated information about the lines.

question is open again. y'all can go ahead and post your answers now.
